# Add x to meta_value and display result in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a function to add a column to woocommerce products admin screen and then fetch the meta value for the key ae_cost_pkr and add 5 to it and echo the result in the newly created column. It works but i am getting an issue where the original meta value is appended to adjacent columns. What am I doing wrong ?

Error can be seen in this image : ibb.co/n3y6n2n

My function is :

```
// add
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_total_sales_1', 20 );
// populate
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'my_total_sales_2' );


function my_total_sales_1( $col_th ) {

    // create colunm
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'ae_cost_pkr' => 'AE Price' ), $col_th );

}

// add 5 to the meta value and display in column
function my_total_sales_2( $column_id ) {

    if( $column_id  == 'ae_cost_pkr' )

    $re = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ae_cost_pkr', true );
    echo $re + 5; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code , you need to update meta if you need to add plus 5

```
// add
add_filter( 'manage_edit-product_columns', 'my_total_sales_1', 20 );
// populate
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'my_total_sales_2' );


function my_total_sales_1( $col_th ) {

    // create colunm
    return wp_parse_args( array( 'ae_cost_pkr' => 'AE Price' ), $col_th );

}

// add 5 to the meta value and display in column
function my_total_sales_2( $column_id ) {

    if( $column_id  == 'ae_cost_pkr' )
    $readd = '5';
    $re = update_post_meta( get_the_ID() , 'ae_cost_pkr', $readd);
    echo $re;
}
```

Comment: Will this permanently change the meta value ? or will the value be changed as long as this function is active ? I donot intend to change the meta value permanently.

Comment: But i donot intend to change it permanently. I just was to see what the result will be if i add 5 to it.

Comment: $re = '5';
$re = $re + get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ae_cost_pkr', true );
echo $re;

Can try this

Comment: But this produces error and appends the previous value to adjacent columns as seen here : https://ibb.co/n3y6n2n